# How do we calculate distance between 2 cities in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I calculate the distance between 2 cities in Google Sheet? I use @Budapest in A1, then @Stockholm in B1…yet the equation =GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE (A1, B1, "driving") just gives me #ERROR!

I use @Budapest in A1, then @Stockholm in B1…yet the equation =GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE (A1, B1, "driving") just gives me #ERROR!

Comment: Is [this](https://www.labnol.org/google-maps-sheets-200817) what you are using? Did you try without the `@` symbols in there?

Comment: I cant add the @ symbol in the formula.

Comment: GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE() is not a google sheets formula

Comment: Just to clarify... `GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE()`, as MattKing has mentioned, is NOT an internal Sheets function/formula. It is a custom function created by a script. AS @Rogue points out, the script was developed by [Digital inspiration](https://www.labnol.org/). Have you installed the script in your project editor?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not a built-in function and requires installing a 3rd-party script.

Always verify scripts come from a trusted source before installing.

Comment: That makes, but where is the 3rd party add-on? What is it called?

Comment: There’s a link in the comments under your initial question.